# How To Catch Exception In Lua? I Am Using LuaJava

Tags: java, lua, luajava

I am using luajava.
When lua execute wrong,I cannot catch exception,and then jdk crashed.
So how can I catch exception in lua?I just catch error like this(java code):

```
LuaState ls = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
ls.openLibs();
String luaPath = "test.lua";
int isCompile = ls.LdoFile(luaPath);
if(isCompile==0){
    log.info(luaPath+" compile success!");
}else{
    log.info(luaPath+" script does not exist or compile failed!");
}
```

When lua has internal error,I cannot catch.
So how can I catch exception in lua?

When lua executes error, JVM shows an error, not an exception.
How can I catch the error in Java?

Comment: Do not know anything about luaJava.  But in lua you could wrap the failing function in a [`pcall`-call](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html).

Couldn't you do the same in luajava with its [`call` function](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/API/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a hack, but the only way I can think of to fix this is to do something like this:

```
LuaState ls = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
ls.openLibs();
String luaPath = "test.lua";
int isCompile;
try {
    isCompile = ls.LdoFile(luaPath);
} catch (Exception ex {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    isCompile = 1;
}
if(isCompile==0){
    log.info(luaPath+" compile success!");
}else{
    log.info(luaPath+" script does not exist or compile failed!");
}
```

Sorry if this isn't what your asking, but the LuaJava doc is worthless, so I have no idea what the specific runtime exception is.

Comment: It isn't the point.Thank you all the same.  When lua executes error,JVM gives an error,not a exception.

Answer (score 0):

LuaState.LdoFile doesn't throw any exceptions.  One approach you might try is to spawn a new thread to attempt running the lua script.